# Multi Dimension array show in blade is getting error undefined offset

Tags: arrays, laravel, loops, multidimensional-array, laravel-blade

Multi Dimension array show in blade is getting error undefined offset 0. I can't show by using loop
Here is my array

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    0 => {#280 ▼
      +"id": 30
      +"category": "wedding"
      +"sub_category": "groom"
      +"image": "30.png"
    }
    1 => {#274 ▶}
    2 => {#249 ▶}
    3 => {#281 ▶}
    4 => {#282 ▶}
    5 => {#283 ▶}
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    6 => {#284 ▶}
    7 => {#285 ▶}
    8 => {#286 ▶}
    9 => {#287 ▶}
    10 => {#288 ▶}
    11 => {#289 ▶}
  ]
  2 => array:6 [▼
    12 => {#290 ▶}
    13 => {#291 ▶}
    14 => {#292 ▶}
    15 => {#293 ▶}
    16 => {#294 ▶}
    17 => {#295 ▶}
  ]
]
```

I want to show this from my blade. here is the blade code I wrriten. but it doesn't work.

```
@for($i=0; $i<count($chunks); $i++)
    <div class="column-grid">
        @for($j=0; $j<count($chunks[$i]); $j++)
            <div class="single-galleries-sub-img">
                <div class="galleries-sub-img">
                    <img src="{{asset('img/galleries/gallery-images/'.$chunks[$i][$j]->image)}}"
                         alt="{{$chunks[$i][$j]->id}}">
                </div>
                <div class="galleries-sub-img-hvr">
                    <a href="{{asset('img/galleries/gallery-images/'.$chunks[$i][$j]->image)}}"
                       data-lightbox="image-4"><i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endfor
    </div>
@endfor
```

in controller i used this function

```
$galleries = DB::table('galleries')
    ->where('category','=',$request->type)
    ->paginate(18);


$chunks = $galleries->chunk(6);
$chunks = $chunks->toArray();

return view('galleries',compact('galleries','chunks'));
```

Can you please help me how can I visible this array in my view page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code it will work for the first array but it will not work for the 2 & 3 array as it is using `$chunks[$i][$j]` where $j will not get 0 element for the 2 & 3 array. that's why you are getting the `undefined error.`

**Because array index is continue in the chunk it is not resetting with each chunk**

> Instead of using for loop you can easily do this with `foreach` loop,
>   also as it is array it good to use foreach loop always:

```
@foreach($chunks as $key => $value) {
    <div class="column-grid">
    @foreach($value as $k => $v) {
        <div class="single-galleries-sub-img">
            <div class="galleries-sub-img">
                <img src="{{asset('img/galleries/gallery-images/'.$v->image)}}"
                    alt="{{$v->id}}">
            </div>
            <div class="galleries-sub-img-hvr">
                <a href="{{asset('img/galleries/gallery-images/'.$v->image)}}"
                    data-lightbox="image-4"><i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @tariqulanik Happy to help you. if it helps you to solved your problem. pls. do up votes and mark it as accepted answer will be much appreciated!!